# How to store nextcloud docker files inside my hdd rather than in a image of docker

Tags: docker, server, containers, docker-desktop, nextcloud

I am actually relatively new to docker and wanted to build a home server for files, I use windows 10, and Docker Desktop for deploying containers.

whenever I store my files on nextcloud I do not see them on my HDD. Rather they are in an image(as far as I know), so I wanted a solution to make all the files appear on my hard drive rather than an image because then I can also use my computer as a rendering server, to render videos and games.

Comment: Which backend for Docker Desktop are you using? It _might_ be possible in the WSL2 one.

Comment: ...that said, I don't know what this has to do with whether you can "also use [your] computer as a rendering server".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy WSL only no WSL2 but i think i can manage WSL2 on my other device, If you know the solution, It would be much appreciated.

Comment: With the WSL2 backend, it should work the same as it does on Linux, so you can see an overlay filesystem with the individual layers. Mind, I still don't understand how this has anything to do with whether you can use your computer as a rendering server.